# phpmailer reply-to and from different (samsung smartphone)

Tags: php, android, email, phpmailer, samsung-mobile

I have a website where sellers post things online, which buyers can respond to via an online contact form.

I send the messages via phpmailer and set the from address to our websites support email address and the reply to address to the email address of the buyer using the contact form.

see below :

```
$mail->AddReplyTo($save['emailaddress'], $save['fullname']);     
$mail->SetFrom('support@mywebsite.com', 'MyWebsite Support');
```

This works fine the majority of times and when the website sellers gets responses, they receive the email from our support@mywebsite.com email address.  Then when they reply in their email account, the email is successfully sent to the Reply-To address of the Buyer.

I have noticed however that we are getting a lot of replies to support@mywebsite.com , where the reply-to isnt working and the email is being sent to the from address.  In every case, I can see that the email is coming from Samsung Galaxy devices or Samsung Smartphones.  It looks as though samsung devices are not using the reply-to field correctly.

Has anyone got any ideas on how this can be fixed ?

Comment: I think you're stuck - you can't use the From address because you'll run into SPF problems. It wouldn't be the first time that someone didn't follow an RFC...